# Keep track of inspiring images (not my own)

Tags: inspiration

Note: this is not a post about keeping track of the pics you took. I use Lightroom for that.

Do ppl take pics / screenshots with the idea of referring to those later, maybe to get inspired before a shoot?

Ideally something that supports:

- tags
- grid view

For now the best I could do is divide images in folders (each folder is a tag, but there is a limit of 1 tag per pic) and open them in grid view.

I guess I could use Lightroom, but I am not sure if I want to import all those pics in my catalog, and I would prefer something more lightweight.

Comment: You could just use a separate catalog.

Comment: or http://pinterest.com

Comment: I prefer such collection to stay private

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough time and energy to track other people's photos with such detail, perhaps **you are not taking enough photos of your own**? (Or you are the photo editor of a publication, in which case, you should be telling, not asking, us about workflow.)

**Any program that tracks tags likely uses a database backend**, which will require "importing" the images. There is no "lightweight" system if your primary criteria is the absence of some import process.

Some options to consider:

- Keep images in your current catalog, but tag them with the source so it's clear they're not your images. This is generally how I track other photographer's images from events I also photographed.
- Use a separate catalog, [as null suggests](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103937/#comment197271_103937).
- Use a site such as pinterest, [as dav1dsm1th suggests](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103937/#comment197272_103937).
- Just dump them in folders with appropriate titles. This is how I collect infographics, but I eventually delete them after absorbing the information. It also seems to be your current method. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.
- Bookmark images at their source.
- Use a note-taking program, such as OneNote or EverNote.
- Just enjoy the images in the moment, and let them work on your subconscious.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do take pics of my own, but I want a better way of tracking inspirational pictures / create moodboard
i think the folder system is annoying because I started tagging images with more than one label. Maybe notes are the best bet for me now